# Broadcast receiver onReceive() is not called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kotlin, android-broadcastreceiver

Broadcast receiver

```
 mBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

                Log.i(TAG,"contact list populate broadcast")

                var action = intent.action

                Log.v("Action is ",action)
                when (action) {
                    GetContactListFromServer -> {
                       println("Get contact list")


                    }
                }

            }
        }

        val filter = IntentFilter(GetContactListFromServer)
        this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter)
```

This is how I am sending broadcast

```
val i = Intent(ContactListActivity.Obz.GetContactListFromServer)
i.`package` = mApplicationContext?.getPackageName()
mApplicationContext?.sendBroadcast(i)
```

This code is working fine till last night. I am not able to debug what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `mApplicationContext` is not equal to `null` when  `mApplicationContext?.sendBroadcast(i)` is invoked?

Comment: yes mApplicationContext is not null @miensol

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

In your activity Inside **onCreate** method declare

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(MyBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("MyFilter"));
```

Then implement the MyBroadcastReceiver in Activity

```
private final BroadcastReceiver MyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String Action = intent.getStringExtra("Action");
            switch (Action){
                case "updatedata":
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    String date_time = intent.getStringExtra("date_time");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Send the Broadcast like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MyFilter");
intent.putExtra("message", message);
intent.putExtra("date_time", date_time);
intent.putExtra("Action", "updatedata");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```