# Broadcast Receiver does not response to PendingIntent with intent.putExtra

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-pendingintent

I am Creating a Pending Intent with the below code:

```
public PendingIntent getPendingIntent(long routeId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdateBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.Keys.POSITION, routeId);
        intent.setAction(Constants.Keys.ACTION_UPDATE_LOCATION);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

And My Broadcast Receive's onReceive() Method is as below:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            //long routeId = intent.getExtras().getLong(Constants.Keys.POSITION, 0);
            if (Constants.Keys.ACTION_UPDATE_LOCATION.equals(action)) {
                Context mContext = context;
                Utility mUtility = new Utility(mContext);
                DBOperations dbOperations = new DBOperations(mContext);
                LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
                if (result != null) {
                    List<Location> locations = result.getLocations();
                    int size = locations.size();
                    Location mLocation = locations.get(size - 1);
                    double dCurrentLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                    double dCurrentLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                    Log.e("Broadcast onReceive:", "lat: " + dCurrentLatitude + " || long: " + dCurrentLongitude);
                    // Send Android O notification
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        OreoNotificationChannel oreoNotificationChannel = new OreoNotificationChannel(context, mLocation);
                        oreoNotificationChannel.showNotification();
                    }
                    Log.e("Update Location :", "Lat : "+ dCurrentLatitude +"|| Long : "+dCurrentLongitude );
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
```

My Manifest File BroadcastReceiver declaration is as below:

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcasts.LocationUpdateBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name= "com.app.Constants.Keys.ACTION_UPDATE_LOCATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I am using the getPendingIntent() method on a button's click event as below:

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.bStart:
                    startBroadcastService(insertedRowId);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    private void startBroadcastService(long routeId) {
            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
            createLocationRequest();
            startServiceLocationUpdates(routeId);
        }


    private void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(Constants.Values.UPDATE_INTERVAL);

  locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.Values.FASTEST_INTERVAL);
     locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(Constants.Values.MAX_WAIT_TIME);
        }

    private void startServiceLocationUpdates(long routeId){
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("You Are Here -> ", "startServiceLocationUpdates() -- > Permission Not Granted");
                return;
            }
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mActivity.getPendingIntent(routeId));
        }
```

The issue is that on executing the code, My getPendingIntent method is called. But the Broadcast Receiver's on Receive method doest not reacts to it.
But, if I remove the

> intent.putExtra(Constants.Keys.POSITION, routeId);

Then My BroadcastReceiver's OnReceive() method reacts and gives the desired output.

Can Anyone tell me what or where i am making the mistake?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `"on Receive method doest not reacts to it"` what you mean by that?

Comment: Did you checked this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43490373/7209777

Comment: @pskink it means if i put log i can see the getPendingIntent() method is called. But BroadcastReceiver is not triggered.

Comment: post the code that uses `getPendingIntent` method, also how can you know that `onReceive` is not called if you don't have any logs on top level of that method??? simply add `Log.d` on top of it

Comment: @pskink Edit the Question with more details

Comment: also how can you know that `onReceive` is not called if you don't have any logs on top level of that method? simply add `Log.d` on top of it and run your code again

Comment: @pskink i had added the logs. here I had removed those.

Comment: @pskink Can you please review my code and see if anything i am missing or making mistake

Comment: as is said `onReceive` is called but most likely your code does not reach `if` branch - again add some `Log.d` on top of that method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204825/discussion-between-pravinsingh-waghela-and-pskink).